# To generate .jar file using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on a task, in which i need to generate the jar file for a java project.

Wondering, how it can accomplish it in jenkins pipeline script to generate jar file for the same....

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I would say you have two options:

1. Transform your project in a maven structure and build it using maven
2. Instead of export it into a jar, export it into an ant build file.

On 2, eclipse will create the ant build file and then you can use ant to build the project on Jenkins. I've used this approach in the past - I believe you will need to tweak the build file to generate the jar, I think ant build file will only compile the classes, you need to add the step of creating the jar file.